# How to display the first data in a list -Pine Script (Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script

I have a code that returns the correct list. I want to show the first candle on that list. Help me
[A lot of candles are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyuXo.png)

```
    `//@version=3
    study(title="LONG Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true)
    lenEma55 = input(55, minval=1, title="Length EMA 55")
    ema55 = ema(close, lenEma55)
    plot(ema55, color=green, linewidth=2)
    long = close > ema55
    plotshape(long, color=green, style=shape.arrowdown, text="LONG",location=location.belowbar)`
```

Comment: What is your short condition? You can use a flag for being LONG, and then check for that flag before drawing the shape.

Comment: Can you give me the example check flags in Pine? pine not my language. Tks so much

Comment: Tell me what your short condition is, then I can help you.

Comment: Short when close < ema55.  @baris yakut

Answer (score 3):

You can use a flag for going LONG and a flag for going SHORT. The important thing about using flags in pine-script is to remember using history reference operator `[]` with them to access the previous state.

Below is an example, where you go LONG whenever `close > ema55`, and go SHORT whenever `close < ema55`.

```
//@version=3
study(title="LONG Test", shorttitle="Test", overlay=true)

lenEma55 = input(55, minval=1, title="Length EMA 55")

isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1])

isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1])

ema55 = ema(close, lenEma55)
plot(ema55, color=green, linewidth=2)

buyCondition = not isLong and close > ema55
sellCondition = isLong and close < ema55

if (buyCondition)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellCondition)
    isLong := false
    isShort = true

plotshape(buyCondition, color=green, style=shape.arrowdown, text="LONG",location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(sellCondition, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="SHORT",location=location.abovebar)
```

Comment: Thank you so much . You helper clear up averry dumb issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: @JaTuan if my answer helped you, could you please mark it as "accepted answer" by clicking the check mark next to my answer?